# verify if a cell contains text google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Sorry,
I think the question is simple for you.

In a google spreadsheet the value must be only number (for example 1 or 245 or 100,234 ) and not text.

How can I do this control? 
not by formula but by code.

I was trying

```
var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var nomefoglio = ss.getSheetName()
var cellaattiva =ss.getActiveRange()
var valore =cellaattiva.getValue()

if (valore ?????? ) {
   cellaattiva.clear({contentsOnly:true}) 
   Browser.msgBox("value not admitted")
  }
```

my question is about what command to put instead ??????

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!isNumeric(e.value)) {
    e.range.clear({contentsOnly:true});
    Browser.msgBox('value not admitted');
  }
}

function isNumeric(value) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you It's go! You know where is a list of function as isNumeric, isNaN ecc. to work with white or null values?